# Best method to handle continuous stream of data input in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing an application where there is continuous stream of data into the database and these data might contain duplication with the data that already inside the database. Hence I need to perform some kind of filtering as well.

Could anyone suggest me a solution to handle such case ?
The one I'm considering at the moment is having a kind of temporary table that contain the data first time it arrives (kind of dump table) and separate stored procedure that will move the clean data to the real table.

Is there any better solution that this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes (depending on the business requirements) the way I handle this is to create a unique index on the table, comprised of the columns you want to use to ensure uniqueness, and set the Ignore Duplicates (or it might be ignore_dup_key) option to true. This way you're letting SQL Server detect the duplicates and it simply ignores them without issuing any sort of error.

This way you don't need to write any filter logic yourself and you're letting SQL Server do all the heavy lifting of checking for duplicates.

Comment: Hi Randy,
Thanks for your suggestion, would like to ask further if there is possible consequences / danger by doing so ? Thank you.